# how to get the index of list of list in java

Tags: java, matrix, indexing, collections, 2d

```
class Result {
    public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
        
        int sum=0,sum1=0;
        for(List<Integer> list:arr){
            for(Integer list1:list){
                if(indexOf(list).equal(indexOf(list1)){
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i was trying to make the sum of 2D diagonal ,but when trying through list of list , I couldn't access the index of each element so I'll add my logic .
So plz tell me , Is there any way to get index of list of list

Comment: Use standard for loop , instead of enhanced for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What about `arr.indexOf(list) == list.indexOf(list1)` ?

Comment: `indexOf` is not a good choice if you have duplicate value in list

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int size = arr.size();
String sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; ++i, --j) {
    sum1 += arr.get(i).get(i);
    sum2 += arr.get(i).get(j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you can get the diagonal elements . Hope this helps

```
 List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    
            List<Integer> innerArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
            innerArr.add(1);
            innerArr.add(2);
            innerArr.add(3);
    
            arr.add(innerArr);
    
            List<Integer> innerArr1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
            innerArr1.add(4);
            innerArr1.add(5);
            innerArr1.add(6);
    
            arr.add(innerArr1);
    
            List<Integer> innerArr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
            innerArr2.add(7);
            innerArr2.add(8);
            innerArr2.add(9);
    
            arr.add(innerArr2);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.get(i).size(); j++) {
// will give you left diagonal
                    if(i==j) {
                        System.out.println(arr.get(i)+"------"+arr.get(i).get(j));
                    }// will give to right diagonal
else if(i+j==arr.get(i).size()-1) {
                    System.out.println(arr.get(i)+"------"+arr.get(i).get(j));
                } 
                }
            }
```

Comment: I believe , if someone is downvoting , they should specify the reason for downvote also

Comment: Harman - Don't worry. I've upvoted it to ameliorate your reputation points. I do not see any problem with your answer. Inexplicable downvotes do not help the community.

Comment: Thanks Arvind  for your kind gesture. I am fine with the downvote, but atleast people should say why they are doing so .

Comment: Arvind that is what I am doing , if you see the equation , I have i+j = arr.get(i).size -1 . In your equation you just brought i to left side of equal(=)

Comment: No problem Arvind!